# How to force stateful widget redraw using keys?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm making an app that pulls data from an API and displays it in a view (MVC style).
I need to figure out how to force my view widget to redraw itself. Right now I tried with ValueKeys and ObjectKeys but to no avail.

There's lots and lots of code so I am going to use snippets as much as possible to keep it clear. (If you need to see more code feel free to ask)

Here's my view widget:

```
class view extends StatefulWidget{

  view({
    Key key,
    this.count = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);
  int count;
  String _action='';
  var _actionParams='';
  var _data;
  Function(String) callback;

  void setAction(String newAction){
    _action = newAction;
  }

  void setActionParams(String params){
    _actionParams = jsonDecode(params);
  }

  void setData(String data){
    _data = jsonDecode(data);
  }

  void incrementCounter(){
    count++;
  }

  @override
  _viewState createState() => _viewState();
}
class _viewState extends State<view>{
  Object redrawObject = Object();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*
    switch(widget._action){
      case '':
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
    */
     return Text("Counter: "+widget.count.toString());
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    this.redrawObject = widget.key;
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

You can see in the commented code that I am planning to change the way the view builds itself in function of the data that gets passed to it.

What I have tried so far is to pass a ValueKey/ObjectKey to the view from main.dart in a constructor and then changing the object at runtime. Unfortunately that did not work.

At the top of my main.dart(accessible from anywhere within main) I have this:

```
Object redraw = Object();
final dataView = new view(key: ObjectKey(redraw));
```

Then in the body of the homepage I have the view and a floating button right under.
If I press the button it should increment the counter inside the view and force it to redraw. Here's the code I have tried so far:

```
body: Center(
        child: dataView
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.badge),
        onPressed: (){
          dataView.incrementCounter();
          redraw = new Object();
        },
      ),
```

From what I understand, if the object that was used as a key gets changed, then flutter should rebuild the state for the widget. So I'm setting my object to a new object but it's not working.

I also tried something like this:

```
onPressed: (){
          setState((){
            dataView.incrementCounter();
            redraw = new Object();
          });
        },
```

Eventually I'd like to use a navigator in conjunction with my view widget (so that we have a back button) but I don't know if this is possible.

It feels a bit like I'm fighting with the framework. Is there a different paradigm I should use (like pages?) or is it possible for me to do it this way?

How do I force my view widget to get redrawn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Göktuğ Vatandaş' answer and GlobalKeys I was able to figure it out.

I made a reDraw() function inside the state and then I called it from my main using a GlobalKey.

Note: Wrapping in a container and using a key for the container is not necessary. Calling setState() is enough to force a redraw.

Here's the new view widget:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

GlobalKey<_viewState> viewKey = GlobalKey();

class view extends StatefulWidget{

  view({
    Key key,
    this.count = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);
  int count;
  String _action='';
  var _actionParams='';
  var _data;
  Function(String) callback;

  void setAction(String newAction){
    _action = newAction;
  }

  void setActionParams(String params){
    _actionParams = jsonDecode(params);
  }

  void setData(String data){
    _data = jsonDecode(data);
  }

  void incrementCounter(){
    count++;
  }

  @override
  _viewState createState() => _viewState();

}
class _viewState extends State<view>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*
    switch(widget._action){
      case '':
        break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
    */
    return Text("Counter: "+widget.count.toString());
  }
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  void reDraw(){
    setState((){});
  }
}
```

Here's where I declare the view widget in my main:

```
final dataView = new view(key: viewKey);
```

Here's where I call the reDraw() function:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.badge),
        onPressed: (){
          dataView.incrementCounter();
          viewKey.currentState.reDraw();
        },
      ),
```

Thanks Göktuğ Vatandaş!

Answer (score 5):

You can [check flutter_phoenix](https://github.com/mobiten/flutter_phoenix/blob/master/lib/flutter_phoenix.dart)'s logic for redraw effect. I think its very useful or you can just use package itself. Basically it does what you trying to achive.

It creates a unique key in state.

```
 Key _key = UniqueKey();
```

Injects it to a container.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      key: _key,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
```

And when you call rebirth it just refresh key and that causes view to rebuild.

```
void restartApp() {
    setState(() {
      _key = UniqueKey();
    });
  }
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. I tried to follow the code on the git without using the phoenix library but it's giving me an error message when I try to call rebirth/refresh. It says: "Method redraw was called on null".
I'm calling rebirth/refresh from my scaffold with the scaffold context. 
Also non-nullable safety does not work right now.
Any ideas?